# Dataframe from CSV gives AttributeError when accessing column

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, anaconda

While putting this trivial table in Ipython I cannot handle it.

I am using pandas '0.19.2' on 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)|
and I am getting this kind of error, handling almost every csv table.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Fatt_eng.csv')

df
Out[82]: 
    Type;Price;Numbers
    0       Purse;13.90;86
    1  Suitcases;192.90;55
    2    Suitcases;54.90;6
    3   Clothing;242.90;98


In[82]: df.Type
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Type'

In[84] df['Type']=df['Type'].str
KeyError: 'Type'
```

Comment: Try `pd.read_csv(..., delimiter=';')`?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Type'`, is because your dataframe has no attribute called `'Type'` and pandas then has a magic method that falls back to look for if there is a column with that name, which there isn't in your dataframe.

The reason there is no column with that name in your dataframe is because you are reading a csv with the european delimiter `';'`, but the default is the english `','`, and you must tell `pd.read_csv` about this.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Fatt_eng.csv', sep=';')
```

will solve your issue